# How to prevent CCleaner from deleting Indexing data?

Tags: ccleaner

CCleaner is a fantastic tool. However, one should know how to use it carefully.

Recently I came across this problem, that with the options that I have, CCleaner deletes the Index data (from Windows Indexing, which helps in faster search). I am mostly affected by the deletion of Index in Outlook 2013.

I have excluded Office 2013 from the options in CCleaner. Need help to identify the specific options for excluding Index data.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### How do I to prevent CCleaner from deleting Indexing data?

Uncheck "MS Search" in "Applications"

> MS Search removes the search index. If you don't want to do this, then simply uncheck the setting.

[image]

Source [Windows search corruption and Index rebuild](http://forum.piriform.com/?showtopic=34030):